# Android custom style/scheme is not applied correctly to button-textColor

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-styles

I'm having trouble with applying a custom scheme(style) to certain views. I have defined my own style in res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <style name="myStyle1">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint"> @color/fuchsia</item>
        <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/olive</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />

</resources>
```

I have applied this style to the main activity of my simple test application, like this

```
   <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/myStyle1" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
           .
           .
           .
    </application>
```

The layout of the MainActivity contains a couple of buttons, some textViews, some of them have the style attribute spiecified explicitly, others should be inhertiting it from the whole activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/silver"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/send_button"
        style="@style/myStyle1"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/relative_activity"
        android:text="@string/rel_activitity_text"
        android:onClick="startRelativeActivity"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_TTT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:text="@string/button_TTT" /> 

    <fragment android:name="my.firstapp.Fragment1"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As far as I can tell, everything in the activity should be stylized according to the style I ahve defined, however, this is what I get

[image: weird scheme]

As you can see, only the buttons with the specified style have their text in red, the other two don't. However, even the white buttons get the correct font from the scheme, so at least some of it is being applied. Why not all of it? Any help would be appreciated, I'm thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a global style for all your buttons you need to do something like this.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="myStyle1">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint"> @color/fuchsia</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/olive</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/myStyle1</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

In your android manifest you should set the theme...

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
       .
       .
       .
</application>
```

You can do the same thing for checkboxs etc. More information from this link.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html

Also I tested this on the following layout. All 3 buttons should have red text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffaaaaaa"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:hint="edit_message" />

<Button android:id="@+id/send_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button_send" />

<Button android:id="@+id/relative_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="rel_activitity_text"
    android:onClick="startRelativeActivity"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/button_TTT"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:textColor="#ffff0000"
    android:text="button_TTT" /> 

<!--<fragment android:name="my.firstapp.Fragment1"
        android:background="#00ff0000"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't change the buttons in any way. What's even weirder is that it doesn't change anything. The textEdits still stay purple, even though I would expect this AppTheme only defines style for buttons, and the rest should go to something default.

Comment: Is your MainActivity doing any graphical changes to the buttons?  That would override the theme.

Comment: Nope, setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    in onCreate()  is pretty much the only thing that's going on in the activity